# I receive in my hosting error_log file errors from a folder that I removed

Tags: php, hosting, error-log

I have a WordPress website that generate many errors in my error_log file,
I deleted the folder with the WordPress site and I still receive errors in my log file.

> PHP Warning: next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php

What is the problem? I deleted the error log file but is regenerated again with errors from the site that has been removed.

Comment: You either removed the wrong folder, or your service provider is using a CDN network that has not yet removed the content.

Comment: For how long has that being happening? It isn't uncommon to have opcode caches and other mechanisms to improve performance, though it's strange that they won't invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely server side caching which is holding onto those files, it's the only explanation for errors coming from nowhere. Check with your provider about ways of disabling it, usually this is done in `.htaccess`

Alternatively after a while the server will update the cache. Also remember to put it back on in production.

Comment: @arkascha my answer probably mislead you, Ive updated it to be more clear. I meant server side caching is caching the files still.

Comment: Again: no. Though server side caching exists it only makes sense for static objects. There is absolutely no sense in caching dynamic scripts. The errors, _if they really show a current time stamp_ , indicate that scripts are executed. That is nothing a cache can do.